# How to load third party Audio Units with AudioKit

Tags: swift, core-audio, audiounit, audiokit

I recently began to work with the [AudioKit Framework on Github](https://github.com/audiokit/AudioKit) and took a deep look into the source of the framework. What I couldn't find but am really curious to know is how to integrate third party **Audio Units**, especially Effects and pass through audio as well as setting, storing and recalling presets.

Since every component inside the framework seems to be an **Audio Unit** there has to be a way to do that, but I couldn't find built in support for audio units.

I guess I have to take that code and write the wrapper myself but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For iOS or OS X?  For iOS, there's a sample application with audio unit extensions at developer.apple.com.

Answer (score 3):

I've added a host manager into the Develop branch now. Please see:
https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKit/tree/develop/Examples/macOS/AudioUnitManager

You'll need to use the latest develop branch build.

Ryan

EDIT: This is now included in AudioKit.